# Toolbox for Computer Hardware

Tags: hardware-rec

I have a lot of computer hardware (hard drives, cables, etc.) and I need a better way to organize.  Could anyone recommend a toolbox intended for this sort of thing, or some other good method for storage?

I have a two drawer wide file that I currently use, with large plastic bags.  It works okay, but I need a better system.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a toolbox but I did get hold of a couple of cheap plastic drawers from asda a while back. I have that many hard drive data cables, spare hard drives, cooling fans, etc etc, that I filled 2 units (4 drawers each) with my computer "crap". The drawers are approx. 1 foot square and 9 inches deep, so just the right size to fit each "category" of crap in to :)

Answer (score 0):

I find my system optimal, and it's almost exactly your current system: I use a large storage tote, but to keep things tidy, I use a large number of "zipper" closure freezer bags.  Then I can keep usb cables, IDE cables, sata cables, serial cables, telephone cords, firewire cables, audio and motherboard cables, and various other bits and pieces, all in their separate sections.

Inside each bag all my cords are either using twist-ties or wrapped around themselves, so you don't end up with a snarl of cables inside each bag.

For small bits like screws, I use 35mm film cannisters and their lids, especially the semi-transparent kind.